# Determine request/response size metrics in Jersey RequestEventListener

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

We want to measure the request and response sizes of our API endpoints. As it [recommended](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e15562) to determine the duration with a `RequestEventListener` we took that approach.

Using the inspector, we can see that the requestEvent contains a property `containerResponse.messageContext.commitingOutputStream.adoptedOutput.delegate.outputStream.count` which contains the actual response size in bytes. However, we cannot access this field using public methods and fields. The accessible method `containerResponse.getLength()` always returns `-1`. The same for `containerRequest.getLength()`.

How can we access the actual request and response sizes, preferably without reflection?

```
private class EndPointPerformanceFilter implements RequestEventListener {
    private long start;

    @Override
    public void onEvent(final RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        switch (requestEvent.getType()) {
            case START:
                start = timeProvider.currentTimeMillis();
                break;
            case FINISHED:
                final long duration = timeProvider.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                final ContainerRequest containerRequest = requestEvent.getContainerRequest();
                final ContainerResponse containerResponse = requestEvent.getContainerResponse();

                System.out.println("Req: [" + containerRequest.getLength() + "] Rep: [" + containerResponse.getLength() +"]");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do the exact same thing before. I never found a solution that involved getting the data directly from Jersey.  I just implemented a `WriterInterceptor` where I set the `OutputStream` to Apache Commons' [`CountingOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html). Then got the count after the writer was finished.

I don't have the exact implementation on hand, but reproducing the functionality, it pretty much goes like this

```
@Provider
public class ContentLengthLoggingProvider implements ReaderInterceptor, WriterInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContentLengthLoggingProvider.class.getName());
    private static final String REQUEST_LENGTH_PROPERTY = "Request.Content.Length";

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext writerContext) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        CountingOutputStream outputStream 
                = new CountingOutputStream(writerContext.getOutputStream());
        writerContext.setOutputStream(outputStream);

        writerContext.proceed();

        long responseCount = outputStream.getCount();
        String requestCount = (String)writerContext.getProperty(REQUEST_LENGTH_PROPERTY);
        String log = "Req: [" + requestCount + "] Rep: [" + responseCount +"]";
        logger.info(log);
    }

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext readerContext) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String requestLength = readerContext.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);
        readerContext.setProperty(REQUEST_LENGTH_PROPERTY, requestLength);
        return readerContext.proceed();
    }  
}
```

This is the dependency I used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I think Guava has a similar `CountingOutputStream` class. So if you are using Guava, you can also use that.